# How To Calculate Text Width With Javascript?

Tags: javascript, text

I need to calculate my text with using JavaScript. But can't find a simple and working method. Please, help me :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are we referring to DOM, or Canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi :) Recently I have found a really simple and handy method.  Just use the Canvas.measureText() method in JavaScript to detect the text width properly:

```js
function displayTextWidth(text, font) {
  let canvas = displayTextWidth.canvas || (displayTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
  let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.font = font;
  let metrics = context.measureText(text);
  return metrics.width;
}
console.log("Text Width: " + displayTextWidth("This is demo text!", "italic 19pt verdana")); //
```

The code and info is taken from this [tutorial](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-calculate-text-width-with-javascript.html) of W3docs.